# Can't connect to database in dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

I used to have this error in Dreamweaver CS6 and I would simply place the _mmServerScripts folder into the root of my local website. Every time I go to select a database it get this error: 
[image: Dreamweaver Error]

I have been searching the net for at least 2 hours now trying to find a solution. It is becoming quite annoying. Everything is working perfectly fine. All the server settings are 100% correct. I have seen various videos on youtube where the user is using a mac and they simply go and grab the _mmServerScripts folder from their dreamweaver folder but I can't seem to locate this. I used to simply use _mmServerScripts folder from dreamweaver CS5.5 and it would end up working perfectly.

I don't know how to fix the issue so does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem
Here what i did to solve the problem

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/first_dynamic_site_pt1.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.